# Sequelize $gt date convert to = date instead of > date

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new using Sequelize and Node.js, but I have issue with date comparison in my code.

```
User.findOne({ where: {
    resetToken: passwordToken,
    resetTokenExpiration: { $gt: Date.now() },
    id: userId
  }})
```

When I run it and check the log, the query is:

```
SELECT `id`, `password`, `email`, `resetToken`, `resetTokenExpiration`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`resetToken` = 'f5779192069c3f1c3d8aae3019cf6172e83d9f07b3741a50caedf793dc3bb43c' AND `user`.`resetTokenExpiration` = '2019-11-19 06:00:00' LIMIT 1;
```

Why is it not using resetTokenExpiration > date, but resetTokenExpiration = date?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the correct range [operators](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#range-operators) which is `[Op.gt]` in this case.

```
User.findOne({ where: {
    resetToken: passwordToken,
    resetTokenExpiration: { [Op.gt]: Date.now() }
    id: userId
  }})
```